# SASS @function to insert property in a @mixin

Tags: function, internet-explorer, sass, grid, mixins

I've trying to find a way to auto-insert a -ms-grid-column-span property in a @mixin every time that I set grid-column with span.

As my store has a lot of access coming from IE I need to fit the grid for it.
Please, have a look at my code:

My @mixin:

```
@mixin grid($row, $column, $gap) {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: $row;
    grid-template-columns: $column;
    grid-gap: $gap;
}
@mixin grid-child($row, $column) {
    grid-row: $row;
    grid-column: $column;
}
```

How I call my @mixin:

```
.anyclass {
   @include grid(auto, 1fr 1fr 1fr, 15px);
   .anyclass-child {
      @include grid-child(1, 2);
   }
}
```

**What I would like to do:**
Include grid-child like `@include grid-child($row, $column);` and in the mixin verify if `$column` contains `'span'` then auto-insert `-ms-grid-column-span` with the right value.

For example

```
grid-template-column: 1fr 1fr 1fr
grid-gap: 15px
```

in IE this code should be `-ms-grid-template-column: 1fr 15px 1fr 15px 1fr`.

And `grid-column: 1 / span 3` should be:

```
-ms-grid-column: 1
-ms-grid-column-span: 5
```

Then, in this case, I would like that the @function auto calculates and insert the `-ms-grid-column-span: 5` property.

**Is it possible? Have an alternative for it?**

Comment: My apologies - I misunderstood your goal. Though this problem probably already has been answered, correct me if I'm wrong - you want to auto-calculate if your column contains a child ```span```, and if it does, apply your styles to it. Is that what you want? Apolgies, Bobbay